# My build Request is not failing when my boost unit test fails

Tags: c++, unit-testing, powershell, boost, azure-pipelines

I have seen that a failing boost unit test will not stop the build from failing.I suspect the build definition is still faulty and future boost test failures will result in the same occurrence; a "green" build request where bad code gets committed. I am using powershell inline script to execute my boost unit test with the following Code

Comment: Can you show an example project which also has the same build results in one drive?

Comment: I am sure about all my build definition has problem,

Comment: I am sure about all my other build definition has same problem, I made intentionally fake changes on my boost unit test and created shelve set for that and I queued my build with this shelve set, so instead of Getiing "Failed"  Or  "Partially succeeded" it will go successful as I showed image in above description, I have tried different run parameters but the result is same.
I want my build step to go "Partially succeeded" . Please help me

Comment: Can you upload an example project you used?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Because of security issues I cannot upload project over here.